# On click select first item on a list

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, ionic-framework

I have a list, I want to select the first item of my list when I select the last item.

Is there a way to do it ?

[image]

Is there a way to handle this please ?

```
<ion-select interface="popover" [ngModel]="selecteduser._id" (ngModelChange)="selectUser($event)" (ionChange)="onChange($event)">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let user of users" [value]="user._id">
      </ion-content>{{ getUserNickname(user }} </ion-option>
    <ion-option>Configuration</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

So I want when I click on my configuration, it will select the first item of my list

There is my ts

```
openConfigPage() {
    this.selectedUser = this.users[0];
    this.navCtrl.push(ConfigPage)
}

selectUser(userId: string) {
    this.selectedUser = this.users.find(b => b._id === userId)
    this.onSelect.emit(this.selectedUser)
}
```

Is there a way to do it with the DOM ?

Comment: Is this angular? Maybe you should add the angular tag to the question as well.

Comment: @arpo Ionic , but it's a DOM manipulation

Comment: @Adelin Sorry thought it's can be done with javascript that's why i put JS.

Comment: Of course it can be done in JS, but what you've shown is neither HTML nor JS, so I can't just start writting JS on my own. The question is not for me to answer, but those who know what you're talking about in that ionic framework, or that ts code

Answer (score 0):

To me, it seems like not much information is being present here. Don't let this discourage you from asking questions in the future, just please make sure to be specific when asking your question and making sure to tag it appropriately.

Since you've asked how to accomplish this in javascript, here is an answer on how to do this in javascript: https://jsfiddle.net/gqvfx850/24/

The idea is that the items are being added in a to the page in a loop, we then access the last item in the loop:

```
//if this is the last item in the loop
if(x === listItems.length - 1)
{
```

And add an event listener for when it's been clicked

```
//add an event listener that also checks the first box when checking
//this one

    radioBtn.addEventListener("click", function()
    {
        //grab the class of all radio buttons
        var firstRadioBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("radio");

        //but you only want to change the first one
        firstRadioBtn = firstRadioBtn[0];
```

we then access the first item in the list, and check it

```
        //set the first button to being checked
        firstRadioBtn.checked = true;
    }, false)
}
```

This idea works assuming that your HTML is being set up by javascript as well, if that's not the case let me know and I can create another fiddle for you.

I'm not familiar with angular, so if this approach doesn't suit you just please let me know why and I can see if I can provide any other assistance on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

## Template

```
Select Last One <select [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" (ngModelChange)="onSelect($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item">{{item}}</option>
</select>

<br><br>
You have selected : {{selectedItem}}
```

## Component

```
export class AppComponent  {
  selectedItem:string; 
  items = [
    'Purab', 'Pashchim', 'Uttar', 'Dakshin'
  ];

  onSelect(selectedItem) {
    let len = this.items && this.items.length;

    this.selectedItem = len && selectedItem === this.items[len-1]?
                          this.items[0]:selectedItem;
  }
}
```

Demo : https://ng-on-lastselect-checkfirst.stackblitz.io

Source : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-on-lastselect-checkfirst

Comment: I have added more details for how to execute it. it checks whether give value in parenthesis is present in array or not. More details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: I have made recent change, you can try now

Comment: Sir i just want when i select the last item, it will select the first one always.

Comment: Sir i don't want to select the last one, i just want when i select it, it will automatically select the first one

Comment: ok. So it will deselect last one which we've clicked and select first one. Is that what you want?

Comment: In that case I have changed my approach